# Промежуточные данные в AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: java, android, android-loader

Нужно в TextView видеть процесс (цикл) который выполняется в AsyncTaskLoader!

*Есть ли в AsyncTaskLoader что то похожее типа:* `onProgressUpdate(Value...v)` `и publishProgress(Value v);` с AsyncTask ???

**Или как получать промежуточные данные ?**

Answer (score 1):

Беглое гугленье предлагает только вариант обращения к основному потоку посредством вызова сего кода:

```
instanceOfActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            //Это выполнится в основном потоке
            //Тут обновляйте вьюхи и т.д.
        }
    });
```

Comment: ,Спасибо за отклик )))  извиняюсь, что туплю: но где это прописывать ?  И чей это метод ?

Comment: Это метод активити. Вызывать его вам надо в момент когда вы хотите что-то в основном потоке сделать. Типа прогресс подвинуть вправо, например.

Comment: Активити вы можете через конструктор вашей задачи передать.

Comment: Оно будет некоректно работать при поворотах (сбрасываться), у AsyncTaskLoader основное приемущество - отработка смены состояний, так получается мы его теряем.

Comment: @pavlofff, я с ним особо не работал, а гугл мне больше ничего не рассказал(